# Integrate external services in a Tomcat environment

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, concurrency

I am looking for a way to integrate external services (like active directory and DB access, web service calls) in a non (or incomplete) Java EE environment such as Tomcat. In a full Java EE server I would (probably) implement a resource adapter (JCA) however in the current project everything runs in a tomcat (v.7.X). This means that many apects like concurrency, transactions, state etc. are not handled by a Java EE container.

It is a stateless setting and the folks told me that there will be some kind of transaction handling (details are due, JTA?). There will be several tomcats in a clustered environment. The number of users is in 3-4 digits range.

My questions are:

- How and when should I initialize external services access? (Use a singleton or a factory etc.?)
- Should I use a third party connection pool for database access? (like [Hikari](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) or the [tomcat internal](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) one)
- How to deal with concurrency? (synchronized blocks, using `volatile`?)